# error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char’ to ‘char [11]’

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm trying to create a member function that allows an user to set member array variables.

I've been looking everywhere but I can't find the problem in my code,

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee
{
   protected:
      string name;
      char ssn[11];
      char id[5];
      char hired[8];
   public:
      Employee(char ssn, char id, char hired);     //Constructor
      Employee(string name);
      ~Employee();      //Destructor
      void setName(string n) { n = name; }
      void setSSN(char i) { ssn = i; }

};

int main()
{
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ssn = i;` You're assigning one character to an 11-character array. I'm not sure why you use `std::string` elsewhere, but not for these.

Comment: void setName(string n) { n = name; } //n is unused here. Should you swap?

Comment: And to add to what @chris said, you cannot assign to arrays in the first place outside of inline initialization.

Comment: Just wondering, what's in your destructor? You shouldn't need anything there in this class. And I think your main problem is that your functions take `char`, but should take `char *` and an `int` for size, or `char (&)[LENGTH_OF_ARRAY]`, to end up with more  than one character. Better yet, `std::string` makes things so much easier and better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look at your `setSSN` function:

```
void setSSN(char i) { ssn = i; }
```

SNN, which most likely means social security number, doesn't consist of just one digit but 11, right? Then why would `setSSN` take as input only one character (digit) by `(char i)`? So `setSSN` function should rather take a string of characters containing SSN of the employee and that string should be of the same flavor as the `ssn` member variable of your `Employee` class in order to let you assign one string variable by another in the body of `setSSN` function. If you are already familiar with the `string` class of the C++ standard library, you should probably use that class for all your string storage and manipulation.

Comment: It should be 12 though including the null termination character :) I like your advice to use std::string.

Comment: @Mahesh I'm not American, didn't know how many characters actually are in SSN, 11, 10 or some other quantity :P